How can I schedule the deletion of user_club?
I'm trying to implement the following logic:

When the user clicks to delete a user_club, a prompt will appear allowing the user to undo this request.
If they don't take any action within 5 seconds, we'll proceed with the deletion.
Alternatively, if the user performs an undo action, I'll cancel the deletion request in the database.


I'm trying to implement using PeriodicTask. However, I haven't been able to complete it yet. Please help me solve the issue I'm facing. Thank you in advance.

This is what I've been trying to accomplish, but it hasn't been successful yet.


models.py
class UserClub(ItemBase):
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_club')
    club = models.ForeignKey(Club, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    roles = models.ManyToManyField(Role)
    membership_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    membership_expiry_date = models.DateField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    subscription = models.ForeignKey(to=Subscription, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='user_club_subscription')
    default = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    reputation_point = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "sport_user_club"
        verbose_name = 'User Club'
        verbose_name_plural = 'User Club'

views.py
    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user_club = self.get_object()
        task = task_schedule_del_user_club.apply_async(args=[user_club.uuid], countdown=10)
        self.response_format['data'] = {
            "task_id": task.id
        }
        self.response_format['message'] = "Club will be deleted after 5 seconds"
        return JsonResponse(data=self.response_format, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    @swagger_auto_schema(methods=['post'], request_body=UndoDeleteClubProcessSerializer)
    @action(methods=['post'], detail=False, url_path="undo-request", url_name='undo-request')
    def undo_request_remove_club(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = UndoDeleteClubProcessSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer_data = serializer.validated_data
        if serializer_data['is_undo_request']:
            try:
                task_schedule_del_user_club.AsyncResult(serializer_data['task_uuid'])
                self.response_format['message'] = "Undo request successfully"
                return JsonResponse(self.response_format, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error(e)
                raise BaseError(_("Cancel an unsuccessful idea or proposal. Please try again!"))

tasks.py
@app.task
def task_schedule_del_user_club(user_club_uuid):
    try:
        user_club = UserClub.objects.get(uuid=user_club_uuid)
        user_club.delete()
    except UserClub.DoesNotExist:
        logger.warning(f"UserClub with id {user_club_uuid} does not exist.")
    except Exception as ex:
        logger.error(f"An error occurred while deleting UserClub: {ex}")


Can be achieved so: add a field like "is_marked_for_delete" to your model, False by default. In "destroy" view set "is_marked_for_delete" to True. In "task_schedule_del_user_club" do not delete model instantly but do it after timeout (5 seconds in your case) and make a check before deletion that "is_marked_for_delete" is still True. In "undo_request_remove_club" set "is_marked_for_delete" back to False.

Hi Andrey!. You're welcome for the idea. I found a solution for myself. I added a PeriodicTask and then revoked the task based on conditions.
